# Google GSuite Certificate Private Key is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, certificate, single-sign-on

What's the best approach on a C# .NET Core Web App to handle a Google Certificate with for a Single sign On that also has SAML options? The Cert file is a pem file

I've been given a certificate to load but no information on where the private key is and how to set it, it seems like a dark art on here with varied opinions yet no straight forward answers

Comment: Does the PEM file contain both `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`?  If so, `X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(filePath)`

Comment: No, Just the BEGIN CERTIFICATE, END CERTIFICATE segment